# Animated cursor wont work in my web application

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, cursor

can anyone help me how to make my downloaded animated cursor work in my web application im using chrome by the way as my default browser.

My problem is the animated cursor wont show in my web application.

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
cursor: url(cursor/lightning.ani), auto;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe getting rid of the `, auto`. From my experience with Anicursor, it is unnecessary in most situations.

Comment: Using `default` instead of `auto` might be more appropriate.

Also, I'd consider adding a second PNG cursor for cross-browser compatibility: `body { cursor: url('cursor.ani'), url('cursor.png'), default; }`

Answer (score 0):

First turn the file into a .gif `cursor: url(cursor/lightning.gif), auto;` but it will not be animated. It is supported in Chrome and firefox but not in IE (internet explorer)